# Example of non integral extension satisfying going up property

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

For an extension of commutative rings $R \subset S$  , the extension is said to satisfy

Going Up (GU) property if for every chain of prime ideals $P\subseteq P_0$  of $R$  with $P= Q \cap R$ for some prime ideal $Q$  of $S$ , there is a prime ideal $Q_0$ of$S$  such that $ Q \subseteq Q_0$ and $P_0= Q_0 \cap R$.

Now my question is obviously we know this condition is true if $R$ is an integral extensions of $S$. But I am searching for a non-integral extension which will satisfy the going up property. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What about field extensions?

Comment: In a way you can say that algaebric extension are special case of integral extension. So I am not counting it.

Comment: Anyone has any example in mind. It will be useful

Comment: I think what Youngsu meant is that any non-algebraic field extension will satisfy the going up property but will not be integral. Note the zero ideal is the only prime of a field.